# How to Maintain Patch Details in Feature File, which is easy to maintain

Tags: automation, cucumber, gherkin, automation-testing

Is there any way we can collapse multiline string containing Patch information. Or what's the Good way to Maintain Patch Details, that doesn't increase the feature file size, with upcoming patch details.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm looking at here. Why is this information in a source file instead of in a project management or version control tool?

Comment: We have some project detail, we might need in future for references. and it will be easy to track the delivery of the same projects and it's changes. Actually it's related to Individual project, Not the entire over-all release, that we are adding in release note in Git.

Comment: That's the purpose of project management tools. If you're using GitHub, GitHub Issues has some basic functionality and there are tools that integrate to offer more. Jira is another common alternative. The point is, though, that this information doesn't belong in the source files of automated tests, but rather these tools and the version control system (which can often be integrated as well).

Comment: Sure Thing, In our project, we are not maintaining requirement any project management tool, Requirements are shared in emails in docs. I have removed details we can track through documents, rest we  have to maintain, like om version, BR Document name, etc.  What other way can be best to maintain some little information regarding the requirement,  will change with release.

Answer (score 0):

Intellij has Custom Code Folding. Using that, we can fold the description which we can open when needed.

[image: Intellij Custom Folding]

[image]